# Group theory, order with permutation of Z

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $S_{Z}$ be the set of permutations of ${Z}$ (note that this is an infinite group!). Find two elements
of $S_Z$ which both have finite order, but whose product has infinite order.

I just am really struggling even picturing what an element of finite order would look like in this group.

Comment: Fix all but a finite number of elements. This gives you an element of finite order, as you'd expect.

Comment: A non-trivial example of an element of finite order is the one that switches $2n$ with $2n+1$ for all integers $n$.

Comment: @AlexWertheim If you take two of those, however, their product aso fixes all but finitely many, so the product does not have infinite order.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: yes, indeed. I was only trying to give an example of an element of finite order, not a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Thinking geometrically, reflections are nice elements of finite order. So, the map $$x \mapsto -x$$ (which reflects about 0), or $$x \mapsto -(x-1)+1$$ which moves everything 1 unit to the left, then reflects across 0, then moves everything back 1 unit to the right; this accomplishes a reflection across 1.

It turns out that, generally, a product of reflections is a rotation, I wonder if it's some kind of unusual rotation here...

Comment: So one of the elements will be -1, and then I need another element that has finite order is this correct?

Comment: Call the first map $f_0$ (since it 'flips' the real line about 0), call the second map $f_1$ (since it 'flips' the real line about 1). Compute $f_0^2 = f_0 \circ f_0$, as well as $f_1^2$. Then compute $f_1f_0$.

Comment: $f^2_0$ would just go back to the original $x$ value?

Comment: Yep, as would $f_1^2$, meaning you've found two elements of finite order.

Comment: And then $f_1f_0$ would be $x+2$ which has infinite order?

Comment: Exactly, the composition $f_1f_0 : x \mapsto x + 2$ will have infinite order, since applying it $n$ times will only send $x$ to $x + 2n$, never to simply $x$.